# Entity framework query add data from select

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

I am having a query written in C# with Entity Framework :

```
            var query = _context.MyTable
            .Where(m => m.Id == request.MessageId && m.MessageStatusId == MessageStatusValue.Error)
            .Select(m => new Message()
            {
                Id = m.Id,
                MessageContentId = m.MessageContentId,
                FullContent = m.FullContent,
                CompanyCode = m.CompanyCode,
                Environment = m.Environment,
                MessageTime = m.MessageTime,
                MessageType = m.MessageType,
                QueueName = m.QueueName,
                QueueSeqNo = m.QueueSeqNo,
                Reciever = m.Reciever,
                ResponseMessageId = m.ResponseMessageId,
                Sender = m.Sender,
                ModTime = modInfo.ModTime,
                ModUserId = modInfo.ModUserId,
                MessageDirectionId = MessageDirectionValue.Out,
                MessageStatusId = MessageStatusValue.NotSent,

            });
```

And next I want to Add it to my database using var entity:

```
            var entity = _context.MyTable.Add(new Message()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        }).Entity;
```

But I want to have every data from Select written above. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to execute the query to get the results from the query. You can execute the query with `ToList()`

```
        var messages = _context.MyTable
            .Where(m => m.Id == request.MessageId && m.MessageStatusId == MessageStatusValue.Error)
            .Select(m => new Message()
            {
                Id = m.Id,
                MessageContentId = m.MessageContentId,
                FullContent = m.FullContent,
                CompanyCode = m.CompanyCode,
                Environment = m.Environment,
                MessageTime = m.MessageTime,
                MessageType = m.MessageType,
                QueueName = m.QueueName,
                QueueSeqNo = m.QueueSeqNo,
                Reciever = m.Reciever,
                ResponseMessageId = m.ResponseMessageId,
                Sender = m.Sender,
                ModTime = modInfo.ModTime,
                ModUserId = modInfo.ModUserId,
                MessageDirectionId = MessageDirectionValue.Out,
                MessageStatusId = MessageStatusValue.NotSent,

            }).ToList();
```

Then you have a list of results which your are selected and you can add them to the db. You can add every single message to the db or use `AddRange(messages)`

You can read more about it [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/addrange-removerange.aspx)

Comment: I suppose, this is not what I meant in my question

Comment: Oh ok. Could you give me more information about your problem?

Comment: I want to copy values from Select statement to Add statement. In select statement I only select values but in Add statement I want to add some new things to my database, like new Id  (guid) or new ModTime

Comment: You can loop through the messages result and take the properties you want instead of the whole object, but I am not sure if it is possible to select and add in the same query. I would do it in two separate steps

Comment: Something like property copying from one object to another.

Comment: First `ToList` and then `AddRange` should do the trick

Comment: As i said first of all you get the query result and then use the properties you want to add new db entries